# Parsing HTTP_USER_AGENT using codeigniter class

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to change :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
```

To Variable with Codeigniter Class

```
$browser = $this->agent->browser();
$browser_version = $this->agent->version();
$platform = $this->agent->platform();
```

Comment: don't understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: ah sorry, i edited this again

Comment: Clarify more precisely what you need. This variables has their [own values](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html), and you wanna change them?

Comment: i wanna change them

Answer (score 0):

Just load `user_agent` library and use its methods)

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');

$browser         = $this->agent->browser();
$browser_version = $this->agent->version();
$platform        = $this->agent->platform();
```

Comment: I know this, but this is not what I'm asking